# Click a button using selenium and xpath

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click a button called Add new alert:

```
<div class="text-right">
<a class="btn btn-primary " data-ajaxcom="" href="/admin/person/59139/alerts/add">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
Add new alert
</a>
</div>
```

Below is my code:

```
    <?php

    // Load up the composer autoloader, which will allow us to use the composer
    // stuff
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
        'firefox', 'base_url'
    );

    // init session:
    $session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

    // start session:
    $session->start();

    $session->visit('http://www.mywebsite.com/admin');

    $session->wait(400 + rand(0, 100));
    $page = $session->getPage();
    $page->fillField('username', 'admin');
    $page->fillField('password', 'password');
    $page->pressButton('submit');

    $session->visit('http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/person/59139');
    function clickbtnwithxpath($xpath)
        {
            $session = $this->getSession();
            $element = $session->getPage()->find(
                '//a[contains(@class, "btn btn-primary ")]',
                $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('//a[contains(@class, "btn btn-primary ")]', $xpath)
            );

            // error handling
            if (null === $element) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not evaluate XPath: "%s"', $xpath));
            }

            // click button
            $element->click();

        }
?>
```

It logs me in and goes to the alert page but it will not click the button. I am a complete newbie with xpath. I think it's here where there must be an error. But I've made an attempt. Could someone please help me get this working?

Answer (score 1):

In absence of ids and data-specific classes, I'd rely on the link text:

```
//a[contains(., "Add new alert")]
```

Comment: sorry that does not work. Could somebody help me click this button

Comment: user name:@alecxe No errors generated in my original script, changing xpath for your link text generates no error too. The result is the same I can't click this button using my current knowledge of php